# Symptom An error occurs when yarn is used to manage project package files

Tags: hadoop-yarn, yarn-v3

I had no problem with yarn@1.22, but when I just updated yarn to the latest version (yarn@3.6.3), I ran into this problem and was hoping to ask for help.
[image]

I searched many articles about yarn management project package errors, but I could not find the answer, because I was very confused.